# Loop to apply Excel worksheet dropdown selections

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to send template emails based on selections in an Excel worksheet.

I want to choose which email template and subject line from a dropdown selection in the worksheet. If empty, I want to skip.

The range with the dropdown options.

```
Dim cellrange As Range, cell As Range
Set cellrange = Range("H3:H500")
```

**I use PowerShell and other scripting languages regularly. My VBA exposure is limited.**

I created variables for the different email templates and the subject lines. I also found code that will send the emails. That part seems ok.

**I receive one email instead of looping through however many emails based on the selections in the sheet.**

I set the email templates and subject line in a range in a different sheet and created variables for them.

```
Set delivery = Sheets("EmailTemplates").Range("A5:A40")
Set address = Sheets("EmailTemplates").Range("A50:A90")
Set deliverysub = Sheets("EmailTemplates").Range("B2")
Set addresssub = Sheets("EmailTemplates").Range("B50")
```

I will also create this for the Meeting template and subject line. I've been trying to get it to work with these two first and getting varied results.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim delivery As Range
    Dim shipping As Range
    Dim meeting As Range
    Dim address As Range
    Dim deliverysub As Range
    Dim shippingsub As Range
    Dim meetingsub As Range
    Dim addresssub As Range
    Dim template As Range
    
    Set delivery = Sheets("EmailTemplates").Range("A5:A40")
    Set address = Sheets("EmailTemplates").Range("A50:A90")
    Set deliverysub = Sheets("EmailTemplates").Range("B2")
    Set addresssub = Sheets("EmailTemplates").Range("B50")
   
    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim cellrange As Range, cell As Range
    Set cellrange = Range("H3:H500")

    For Each cell In cellrange
    If cell.Value = "" Then
    Next cell
    
    ElseIf cell.Value = "Delivery" Then
    Set rng = delivery
    Set SubjectLine = deliverysub
    
    ElseIf cell.Value = "Shipping" Then
    Set rng = address
    Set SubjectLine = addresssub
    
    ElseIf cell.Value = "Meeting" Then
    Set rng = meeting
    Set SubjectLine = meetingsub
    End If
    Next cell
   
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "myemail@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = SubjectLine
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .SEND   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
    
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function



End Sub
```

Comment: You're looping over the cells in the range but only sending a mail when you're done with looping - looks like the "send email" code needs to go inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

More like this:

```vb
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTemplates As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, subj As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set wsTemplates = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EmailTemplates")
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In ws.Range("H3:H500").Cells
    
        'What type of template are we using?
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "Delivery"
                Set rng = wsTemplates.Range("A5:A40")
                subj = wsTemplates.Range("B2")
            Case "Shipping"
                Set rng = wsTemplates.Range("A50:A90")
                subj = wsTemplates.Range("B50")
            Case "Meeting"
                'etc etc
            Case Else
                Set rng = Nothing 'not sending anything
        End Select
    
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then 'sending?
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutMail
                .To = "myemail@email.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = subj
                .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
                .SEND   'or use .Display
            End With
        End If
    
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, thanks so much for pointing that out and posting updates! I am going to work on this more today and will test this out. Again, I'm very thankful for your response Tim! To answer your question, i just have the email content to send posted in those ranges and that part seems to work well. For instance, the Delivery Email Template is posted in this range, Case "Delivery" Set rng = wsTemplates.Range("A5:A40"). I'm referring to it as a template, however, it's just the email content posted in those cells.

Comment: Tim, that worked PERFECTLY! Exactly what i was looking for. Much appreciated sir!